# Shared Django field across model instances

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django, and need help with something quite basic.

Suppose we created a model representing a worker, and we wanted to create a function to calculate how much each worker made after taxes. For simplicity, a worker has a take-home pay of their gross income times their tax rate, and the tax rate is a variable that all workers share.

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    gross_income = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    def take_home_pay(self):
        return self.gross_income*tax_rate
```

I know how to store each worker's gross income in the database. I did it using models.FloatField. Here's my question: how would I store the tax rate, which is shared across workers, in the database?

Comment: You can make an extra model `TaxRate`, and then define a `ForeignKey` from `Worker` to `TaxRate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `TaxRate` model and attach a relation on your `Worker` model. Additionally, you can implement the `__mul__` and `__rmul__` methods so you can the `TaxRate` instance directly in your computation.

```
class TaxRate(models.Model):
    rate = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.rate * other

    __rmul__ = __mul__


class Worker(models.Model):
    gross_income = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    tax_rate = models.ForeignKey(TaxRate)

    def take_home_pay(self):
        return self.gross_income * self.tax_rate
```